# Code Igniter - MySQL query using where and like

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have searched every answer but nothing describes what I want or maybe I didn` t comprehend them quite right. So here goes my question. I want a "complex" query like this:

```
select * from MyTable
where PropertyA='$propertyValue'
and (id like '%$someValue%' or name like '%$someValue%' or description like '%$someValue%') 
order by id desc limit 10 offset $offsetValue
```

How can I write this query in code igniter? `$propertyValue, $someValue, $offsetValue` are all php variables. And of course I need to avoid sql injection. I have also tested this in phpmyadmin and my query works fine.

Comment: How much experience Do you have with Code igniter and MVC's? Have you got some Code for us?

Comment: Use this.. $res = $this->db->query("select * from MyTable where PropertyA='$propertyValue' and (id like '%$someValue%' or name like '%$someValue%' or description like '%$someValue%') order by id desc limit 10 offset $offsetValue");  return $res->result();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For SQL injections, using binded queries and Active records is safe, it will save you from SQL injections as the framework does all of the work of escaping vulnerable user input.

You just write your code in Active record FOR 3.X version

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('PropertyA', $propertyValue);
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->like('id', $someValue);
$this->db->or_like('name', $someValue);
$this->db->or_like('description', $someValue);
$this->db->group_end();
$this->db->order('id','desc')
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);// add your limit here
$this->db->get('MyTable');
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you. Just a small change, the correct way to order the items is $this->db->order_by('id','desc')

Comment: Does the group start and group end describe the parenthesis?

Comment: Check this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping